# Best approach to fetch very long list of objects from back-end and load it in UI?

Tags: angular, performance, spring-mvc, httprequest, ag-grid-ng2

I have a httprequest which will fetch the list of users belonging to a company. All the users will be fetched in a single shot. I have tested my application with small amount of data and it worked. Now as the data grows its taking lot of time to fetch the records and load it in UI.

I'm using Spring MVC for back end, Angular 4 for front end and using Ag-grid as well.

What will be the best approach to fetch the data and load the UI without the end user needing to wait for long time seeing the loading page?

Comment: lazy loading would be the best approach... ref - https://medium.com/@realTomaszKula/lazy-load-images-in-30-lines-of-code-3fe801223ffa

Answer (score 0):

Infinite Scrolling (Continuous Scrolling) i.e. Loading additional data when the user scrolls to see those additional data is one of the best approach to show large amount of data on demand.

There are many ways to implement infinite scrolling. You can customize your own implementation or can use the npm packages available depending up on your need.